# What could explain the browser intermittently not loading some CORS (crossorigin) javascript files?

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, cors, http-caching

I recently added the crossorigin attribute to certain script tags to enable my scripts to gather error information from scripts from a different subdomain. I added the header in nginx to allow the cross-origin request.

Since then, I occasionally have a page load without the browser requesting certain javascript files from the server. Reloading the page resolves the issue, but this has happened several times now.

I think this is related to CORS, but since it works most of the time, I have no idea how to reproduce it.

Here are some excerpts from my code:

Nginx configuration contains this rule for javascript files in a certain location:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
```

My script tag in the php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print "$host/js/$filename?v=$version";?>" crossorigin></script>
```

When my page loads, I can see in Firebug that the script tag is correct, but in the Firebug Net tab there isn't even a request shown. Normally there is a request shown, even if it uses a cached version of the file.

I found one question here which I thought might be related:
[all of my browsers are not sending the origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228839/all-of-my-browsers-are-not-sending-the-origin-header/14238351#14238351)
But thinking about it further, I think there should be an initial request which would fail and which would show in Firebug.

Does anyone have any theories on why this might be happening?

Edit:
I added a separate access log for my CORS requests. Any file in the location which gets Nginx adding the CORS header also gets logged in a new access log.

When the page fails to load a javascript file, Nginx is logging a request with a 304 status (not modified). That means that Nginx got a conditional request for the resource only if modified, and Nginx sent back the 304 and nothing else. If the cached version was not loaded with the CORS header, then maybe the javascript can not be executed.

I have a version number which I append to the src of the script tag as shown above. This version number has changed. So shouldn't that cause the browser to re-request all these resources as if they had a different file name? I think the browser should have been treating these as uncached resources. There should not have been any requests that could result in a 304. What could be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps the resource fails with some error that prevents the cors header from being sent? Anything in the server error logs?

Comment: No errors in the server logs. It's just a static javascript file, so very little that can fail server side.

Comment: I got more log information and edited the question.

Comment: Weird. But: `That means that Nginx got a conditional request for the resource only if modified, and Nginx sent back the 304 and nothing else.` it seems to me that *that's* the root of the problem and would need modifying somehow?

Comment: That's what I thought too. But whenever I change that version number, it shouldn't be checking for modified anymore, because each resource has a different url. Those javascript files are set to "expires 30d;" in my Nginx config. But the browser should be requesting it as a new url, not checking against a cached copy.

Comment: If it's not a huge hassle to do in nginx, maybe switch to having actually different *file names*, I've heard of cases where a different parameter string wasn't enough to force a reload (but then, those were extreme edge cases with niche products, they shouldn't apply to your situation)

Comment: It wasn't too hard to add a rewrite in nginx to allow me to add a version number in the path to the resource. This didn't solve the problem though. I did find an article that said query strings are not the best way to control caching: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what's causing this. First, we need more information about the configuration.

I have 3 hosts, a.my.com, b.my.com, and c.my.com. The static files are all served from c.my.com, and the html and php are served from a.my.com and b.my.com.

I added the crossorigin attribute to my script tags so I could get useful error information from my scripts. See the SO question describing this issue here: [Cryptic "Script Error." reported in Javascript in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox)

I am using the requesting host as the allowed origin instead of *, as a precursor to whitelisting allowed origins. See this question for more: [How to properly setup nginx Access-Control-Allow-Origin into response header based on the Origin header from the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499320/how-to-properly-setup-nginx-access-control-allow-origin-into-response-header-bas)

My nginx configuration has a long expiration for static content so stuff is cached and not loading down my server with repeated requests. I append a version number to the url for static content so it can be re-requested when something changes. The version number comes from my version in svn, so when I update the server files to the newest version, browsers will all start loading a new url for each static file.

So here's what's happening:

A new user visits a.my.com and loads the page. Javascript files 1 through 5 are loaded from c.my.com for use on a.my.com. Nginx sends them with an origin header allowing "a.my.com" and a far future expiration date. This page works fine, and the javascript loads successfully.

The user then goes on to the other part of the site at b.my.com and loads the page. Javascript files 1 through 10 are requested from c.my.com. Files 1 through 5 are the same files as were loaded for a.my.com. The browser knows it has those files in its cache, so it asks nginx for their status. Nginx replies with a 304 (not modified) and the browser goes on to request the next file.

So now the browser has loaded files 6 through 10 from c.my.com, and has looked in the cache for files 1 through 5. The cached files have their allow origin header attached, and this says "a.my.com" is the allowed origin. The page requesting the files is on b.my.com, so it doesn't match and isn't allowed to use them. So it silently discards them and shows the user a page with missing javascript.

Solutions:

One solution is to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin with a value of * to allow any origin. This would mean that the cached file is allowed for the current origin even if they didn't initiate the first download. There are security implications for this, as discussed in this SO question: [When is it safe to enable CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713644/when-is-it-safe-to-enable-cors/9725695#9725695)

A second solution is to make each origin use a different url for the same static file. This forces the browser to cache them separately. That allows the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to be specific to a single origin. The cost is more resource requests coming to the server, and the user's browser uses more memory and storage for cached resources.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for taking the time to write up your findings.

Answer (score 2):

You need Vary:Origin in your response headers.