# Caching of Access-Control-Allow-Origin value cross-site

Tags: http, nginx, cors, browser-cache, http-caching

I am trying to write an nginx config that will handle two sites on both http and https, it seems to work as long as a client never visits both sites, but if they do there are caching/cross-site issues.

```
# Allow cross origin
location ~* \.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|json)$ {
    if ($http_origin ~* (https?://(admin\.)?example\.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    }
}
```

So if I load example.com, everything works, but then when I load admin.example.com I get issues like this

> (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
>    http://origin.example.com/js/data-lib/currency.json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http:// example . com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http:// admin . example . com' is therefore not allowed access.

As near as I can tell this is because the browser cached the original request with the header it came with, and now it's denying me even though another request from the server would allow it. The proof is if I check the Disable Cache in the Chrome Developer tools then the issue never happens.

How do I solve this issue? Is it possible to do multiple domains + ssl/http all in one config, or is it necessary to split this up based on the domain and protocol being requested?

(Sorry about the horrible spaces in my example, apparently StackOverflow thinks I'm trying to post links when I'm just writing examples)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add the `Vary` response header with the value `Origin`, that should have the  effect of causing any browser to skip its cache and make a new network request when the value of the `Origin` request header is different from the `Origin` value of the request it cached from.

See [the relevant part of the HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4). So you could update your nginx config to do this:

```
# Allow cross origin
location ~* \.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|json)$ {
    if ($http_origin ~* (https?://(admin\.)?example\.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    }
    add_header 'Vary' "Origin";
}
```

You can read up more in [the MDN article on the `Vary` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary).

> The `Vary` HTTP response header determines how to match future request
> headers to decide whether a cached response can be used rather than
> requesting a fresh one from the origin server. It is used by the
> server to indicate which headers it used when selecting a
> representation of a resource in a content negotiation algorithm.

…and in the MDN `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` article’s [CORS and caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#cors_and_caching) section:

> If the server sends a response with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value that is an explicit origin (rather than the "`*`" wildcard), then the response should also include a [`Vary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary) response header with the value `Origin` — to indicate to browsers that server responses can differ based on the value of the `Origin` request header.

…and in [the Fetch spec itself](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches):

> If your requirements are more complicated than setting
> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` or a static origin, use the `Vary: Origin` response header.
>
> If `Vary` is *not* used and a server is configured to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for a certain resource only in response to a CORS request: When a user agent receives a response to a non-CORS request for that resource, the response will lack `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and the user agent will cache that response. If the user agent then encounters a CORS request for the resource, it will use that cached response from the previous non-CORS request — without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
>
> But if `Vary: Origin` is used in the same scenario, it will cause the user agent to fetch a response that includes `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, rather than using the cached response from the previous non-CORS request lacking `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Note that you need to set `Vary: Origin` for requests with a non-matching origins as well (i.e., add `add_header 'Vary' "Origin";` outside the `if` statement), and due to the way header inheritance works in nginx, you need to leave `add_header 'Vary' "Origin";` inside the `if` statement, too (i.e., it won't be inherited): http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

Comment: Note that you may need to clear your browser cache after implementing this change.

Comment: This answer covers the logic & `Vary` problem well, but using `if` inside a location is fraught with danger unless you're doing only `return` or `rewrite … last`; see [If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). Other answers show better implementations of setting headers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313581/315024 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69571803/315024