# nginx config to enable CORS with origin matching

Tags: nginx, cors, cross-domain, preflight

I've tried to use [a very popular config](https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487) for nginx, which enables CORS and supports origin matching using regular expressions.

Here's my config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        if ($http_origin ~ '^http://(www\.)?example.com$') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$http_origin";
        }

        # Handling preflight requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this config must use two conditions: one to match the origin domain name and another one to capture preflight requests. So when the second condition is matched, the headers from the first conditions are not added to the response.

According to the [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) official article, this is an expected behavior for nginx.

If `If Is Evil` how do I enable CORS in nginx then? Or maybe there is a way to overcome this limitation somehow?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467671/how-can-i-add-header-conditionally-in-nginx-configuration/34295867#34295867 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017524/how-to-add-headers-in-nginx-only-sometimes/31026765#31026765

Comment: The posts mentioned by @sideshowbarker is not just related but quite crucial here because only `add_header`s inside last `if` works in this case

Answer (score 20):

You can try to use `map` istead of the first `if` block:

```
map $http_origin $allow_origin {
    ~^http://(www\.)?example.com$ $http_origin;
}
map $http_origin $allow_methods {
    ~^http://(www\.)?example.com$ "OPTIONS, HEAD, GET";
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $allow_origin;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods $allow_methods;

        # Handling preflight requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

nginx will refuse to add an empty HTTP headers, so they will be added only if `Origin` header is present in request and matched this regex.

Comment: An interesting idea, thanks! Is there a way to deduplicate the regex though?

Comment: The only way I see is to use an additional variable with a third `map` block, something like `map $http_origin $use_cors_headers { ... }`, and then check this variable value in two others, but I don't sure if this would be any preformance improvement.

Comment: only `add_header`s inside `if` works in such cases for me and some other developers (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467671/how-can-i-add-header-conditionally-in-nginx-configuration )

Answer (score 3):

A more compliant solution is a bit more involved but does de-duplicate the regex for domain matching, and can be placed into snippets.

I created the file `/etc/nginx/snippets/cors-maps.conf` which must be `include`d inside the `http { ... }` block. It contains rules like so:

```
# always set value to append to Vary if Origin is set
map $http_origin $cors_site_v
{
    ~. 'Origin';
}
# set site-specific origin header if it matches our domain
map $http_origin $cors_site_origin
{
    '~^https://(?:[-a-z\d]+\.)+example\.com$' $http_origin;
}
# validate the options only if domain matched
map '$request_method#$cors_site_origin#$http_access_control_request_method' $cors_site_options
{
    # is an allowed method
    '~^OPTIONS#.+#(?:GET|HEAD|POST|OPTIONS)$' okay;
    # requested an unknown/disallowed method
    '~^OPTIONS#.' nope;
}
# set value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin only if domain matched
map '$request_method#$cors_site_origin' $cors_site_acao
{
    '~^(?:GET|HEAD|POST)#.' $cors_site_origin;
}
# set value of Access-Control-Allow-Credentials only if Origin was allowed
map $cors_site_acao $cors_site_acac
{
    ~. 'true';
}
```

Then `/etc/nginx/snippets/cors-site.conf` which can be `include`d inside multiple `location { ... }` blocks:

```
# only using "if" safely with a "return" as explained in https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/
# return early without access headers for invalid pre-flight, because origin matched domain
if ($cors_site_options = nope)
{
    add_header Vary $cors_site_v;
    return 204 '';
}
# return early with access headers for valid pre-flight
if ($cors_site_options = okay)
{
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors_site_origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials $cors_site_acac;
    add_header Vary $cors_site_v;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS';
    # probably overkill, gleaned from others' examples
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, Cookie, DNT, If-Modified-Since, Keep-Alive, Origin, User-Agent, X-Mx-ReqToken, X-Requested-With';
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;
    return 204 '';
}
# conditionally set headers on actual requests, without "if", because directive ignored when values are empty strings ("map" default)
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors_site_acao;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials $cors_site_acac;
add_header Vary $cors_site_v;
```

The `#` in the values to match aren't special, they simply serve as separators to allow tests with multiple input variables. Extra domains can be added to the `map` for `$cors_site_origin`, but would need a bit of tweaking to support domains with different allowed options/headers.

Comment: This is a damn good answer, you should probably add some methods like PATCH, DELETE, PUT to sweets your needs. Also you probably want to add always to all add_header lines as without that you won't have headers set on some response code of your backend server (ie 401, ...).

Answer (score 1):

The [only solution](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/b1edbdb352a6d9d6909a7f879e4ca7ea) I've found so far is a hack to use a variable to aggregate multiple conditions and then match it with only a single if statement, therefore duplicating some directives:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        set $cors '';
        set $cors_allowed_methods 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET';

        if ($http_origin ~ '^https?://(www\.)?example.com$') {
            set $cors 'origin_matched';
        }

        # Preflight requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            set $cors '${cors} & preflight';
        }

        if ($cors = 'origin_matched') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
        }

        if ($cors = 'origin_matched & preflight') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods $cors_allowed_methods;
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the details of your nginx setup, it's not going to work anyway, because the CORS header's you're returning are incorrect...

Specifically:

- For preflight (OPTIONS) requests, the following are the only meaningful CORS response headers: `Access-Control-Allow Origin`, **(required)**, `Access-Control-Allow Credentials` (optional), `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, **(required)**, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, **(required)** and `Access-Control-Max-Age`, (optional). Any others are ignored.
- For regular (non-OPTIONS) requests, the following are the only meaningful CORS response headers: `Access-Control-Allow Origin` **(required)**, `Access-Control-Allow Credentials` (optional) and `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` (optional). Any others are ignored.

Note those **required** headers for pre-flight requests - currently you're only passing two of them... Also, note that you *don't* need to return `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` for a non-OPTIONS request - it's not 'valid', so will be ignored.

As far as your specific nginx issue goes, I think **@Slava Fomin II** has the correct-est answer...

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is used only for the preflight requests. I've missed that. However, what value should I return in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` if I don't care about request headers at all? I'm serving mostly static content. Actually, do I need to implement the preflight requests handling for such scenario at all or simple CORS requests are enough for all browsers?

Comment: Well the fetch spec (which defines CORS, and is at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol) was changed a couple of years ago to allow '*' for additional headers - specifically "**Note:** For `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers the value `*` counts as a wildcard for requests without credentials. For such requests there is no way to solely match a header name or method that is `*`." But it's not clear on whether browsers actually support this.

Comment: So if `Access-Control-allow-Headers: *` isn't supported (and no-one seems to know if it actually is), then your best bet is to extract the value of the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` request header and 'mirror it back' in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header.

Comment: it makes sense, but what if I want to tell the browser — "send me the minimal amount of headers possible"? What should I put in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` then? And how browser will treat the response if `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers is missing from it entirely?

Comment: Well the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` (ACRH) request header is the browser telling the server "I'm about to make a request, and these are the headers that I'm going to send as part of the request". The server can't control which headers will be sent in the request... Your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (ACAH) response header needs (at a minimum) to include any of those headers which aren't 'simple' headers. If you don't send the ACAH response header from your server, the request will fail.